Creación de refresh token
Hola buena tarde a todos espero me puedan ayudar,
Estoy creando un portal, pero mi token llega a la hora de vencimiento y no quiero que me mande al login si no que haga un refresh token y así siga trabajando mi usuario. Ya tengo la parte que envía mi refresh a un api y me devuelve el nuevo token correctamente, el problema es que no me deja insertar el nuevo token.
Aquí dejo mi código.
public async void ValidTokenAuth(IHttpContextAccessor context)
    {
        var access_token = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("Access_Token"))?.Value;
        var refresh_token = context.HttpContext.User.Claims.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Type.Equals("Refresh_Token"))?.Value;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(access_token))
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var jwt = tokenHandler.ReadToken(access_token) as JwtSecurityToken;
            var tokenDate = jwt.ValidTo.ToLocalTime().AddMinutes(-10);

            if (DateTime.Now > tokenDate)
            {
                // Aquí se verifica si existe un refresh token
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(refresh_token))
                {
                    // Lógica para generar un nuevo token de acceso usando el refresh token
                    var newAccessToken = await GenerateNewAccessToken(access_token);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newAccessToken))
                    {
                        // Actualizar el token de acceso en las cookies
                        var oSecurityTokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
                        var oJwtSecurityToken = oSecurityTokenHandler.ReadJwtToken(access_token);
                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                        {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, oJwtSecurityToken.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Fullname").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault()),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, oJwtSecurityToken.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "role").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault()),
                            new Claim("Refresh_Token", oJwtSecurityToken.Claims.Where(c => c.Type == "Refresh_Token").Select(c => c.Value).SingleOrDefault()),
                            new Claim("Access_Token", access_token)
                        };
                        var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(
                            claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                        var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                        {
                            IssuedUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(10)
                        };
                        context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                        context.HttpContext.SignInAsync(
                            CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
                            new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
                            authProperties).Wait(); // Espera sincrónica para evitar problemas de concurrencia
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private async Task<string> GenerateNewAccessToken(string Token)
    {
        var url = $"{_configuration["IdentityUrl"]}identity/refreshToken";
        var content = new StringContent(JsonSerializer.Serialize(new RefreshTokenExternalModel { Token = Token }),
           Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var httpClientUsuario = new HttpClient();
        var response = await httpClientUsuario.PostAsync($"{url}", content);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IdentityExternalGeneralResponse>(
                await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(),
                new JsonSerializerOptions
                {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
                });
            var newAccessToken = result.AccessToken;

            return newAccessToken;
        }
        return null;
    }

El error que me marca es que context.HttpContext es un objeto null, estoy implementando mal o existe alguna otra forma para realizarlo?
Espero me puedan ayudar.

Debes explicar correctamente tu problema, has agregado 2 funciones que no sabemos como se gatillan, dices que "el problema es que no me deja insertar el nuevo token" no se insertan donde??.- "El error que me marca es que context.HttpContext es un objeto null," en que línea te marca eso?, context es un argumento de tu primera función quien invoca esa función?, estas funciones están en un controller???
